# Happiness for laypeople

Tags: ethics, sutras, lay-buddhism, layman, lay-practices

I'm right now working on [an application](https://sunyatazero.github.io/buddhist-well-being-pyqt5/) for increasing happiness in everyday life, inspired by practical teachings in Buddhism about happiness for laypeople.

My question is: What did the Buddha say about happiness for laypeople?

I have found these Sutras helpful:

- [Sigalovada Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigalovada_Sutta)
- [Dighajanu Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dighajanu_Sutta)

What else did the Buddha say about happiness for laypeople?. (Is there a compilation of teachings regarding this?)

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Answer (score 2):

There is a handy list of linked suttas at this link [IV. The Happiness Visible in This Present Life](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/in-the-buddha-s-words/29)

P.A. Payutto's [A Constitution for Living](https://www.mahidol.ac.th/budsir/Contents.html) is most excellent & includes the sutta reference for each list.

The [Maha-Mangala Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.2.04.piya.html) is an excellent sutta.

Comment: Thank you for this! The Maha-Mangala Sutta is a Sutra that i have been looking for for some time (after seeing a translation of it but without any Sutra name)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be happy, just give up everything in your mind . What I meant was do not have any kind of attachment to anything, at least try not to have attachments , the lesser the number of attachments the more happy you will be.

Example :

You can have every physical thing in the world , (money , cars, houses etc) but do not have any kind of attachment towards them in mind. That does not mean give up everything and go to be a monk . 
It means give up everything just from your mind , physically you work with them use them and do everything, but without making an attachment in mind. If you do this , you will be happier than ever ,